# Get collection with ordered quantities for admin grid

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, grid, product-collection

I added a custom grid in admin panel which shows all the Best seller product collections. (*configurable products*). The admin grid has the following columns:

```
entity_id     product_name    sku      ordered_qty
```

I am getting the Best seller product collection by using `Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection');` but while filling the admin grid, I am changing the product collection to related to catalog product collection. as shown below:

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $from = /* some date */;
    $to = /* some date */;

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setStoreId($storeId)
        ->addOrderedQty($from, $to)

    $common_ids = array();

    foreach($collection as $product) {
        $common_ids[] = $product->getId();
    }

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $common_ids)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    parent::_prepareCollection();
    return $this;
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I am getting the product collection twice because the `"reports/product_collection"` is not filling the admin grid. So, I did `"catalog/product_collection"` again to the collection which is filling the admin grid.

But `"catalog/product_collection"` is not filling the column `ordered_qty` because the `ordered_qty` column values are being prepared by `"reports/product_collection"`.

How should I get the values for `ordered_qty` ?

Comment: please let me know if you can't understand my explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already getting the `ordered_qty` from the first collection.
You can remember them in an array by id and attach them to the second collection after calling `parent::_prepareCollection`.